# How do I obtain a string from a list and compare it to another string?

Tags: python-3.x

So basically I'm making something fun for myself, and I've run into a problem.
I have a list of illegal items someone can't put into a username string.
Basically, if someone inputs a username, and it contains something in the variable illegal_items, it should not let them input the username.
Problem is, I cannot get it to work properly. Here is what I've tried.

```
username = "roboticperson"
illegal_items = ['test', 'robotic', 'emphatic']

if any(illegal_items in s for s in username):
    print("Your username cannot contain any illegal items.")
else:
    print("Hello, "+username+"!")
```

WHAT IT SHOULD SAY:

```
Your username cannot contain any illegal items.
```

WHAT IT SAYS INSTEAD:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

If this is a duplicate of another thread, my apologies.

EDIT: I'm trying to make it so that anything within the variable illegal_items flags the username as invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for s in username is iterating through the username by character. 
Therefore what you are essentially doing is:

is test in r?

is test in o?

do this instead:

```
username = "roboticperson"
illegal_items = ['test', 'robotic', 'emphatic']

if any( s in username for s in illegal_items):
    print("Your username cannot contain any illegal items.")
else:
    print("Hello, "+username+"!")
```

This checks if

is test in roboticperson? //false

is robotic in roboticperson? //true